# Lightning component iframe src attribute not taking the correct value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, iframe

I am trying to add a url to iframe and is getting the following error

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <iframe src="https://xxx.yyy.com/SFDClogin.aspx?SessionId={!$Api.Session_ID}&ServerURL={!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_180}&Document="
            width="100%"
            height="1000px"
            sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-forms"
            scrolling="auto"/>
</aura:component>
```

Error:

> Failed to save iframerender.cmp: 0Ad0K000000RjXs:2,101: ParseError at
>   [row,col]:[3,101] Message: The reference to entity "ServerURL" must
>   end with the ';' delimiter.: Source

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check this link:https://github.com/nikitakarpenkov/iframe-lightning-component/tree/master/aura/IframeComponent

Comment: it will give the same issue when I try to use the URL in design

Comment: why don't you use a [canvas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_framework_intro.htm) with a [force:canvasApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_canvasApp.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues here:

1. Lightning does not have access to API session ids.
2. Lightning expressions are of a different syntax ({!v.value} versus {!value})
3. Lightning is rendered client side and VF is rendered server side
4. Lightning markup must be the entire attribute value:

   <a href="{!v.value}"> //ok

...it cannot be part of an attribute value

```
   <a href="a + {!v.value}"> //will not compile
```

5. Moreover, by exporting the Salesforce session Id to a third party via a URL, you are not only compromising the security of all of your users but may be in violation of your master subscription agreement or partnership agreement. When you take authentication data of your salesforce users and put them in a URL, you will leak that URL via referer header and are also sharing private authentication data with third parties.  If you want to integrate a third party site, use OAuth to give that site its own authentication data rather than copying the salesforce session id and sharing it with other parties acting on behalf of the user.

Comment: HI Robert. Thank you for the input. As far as security is concerned its not a third party it is our internal website where we want our user to be redirected.

Comment: But you should still not be stealing the user's salesforce session id. They should have their own session id in your website. In order to authorize the user, use OAuth. And the referer leakage issue as well as logging that session id in your server logs remain as threats.

Comment: In other words, the session id does not belong to you, it belongs to the user. It's not something to pass around to other websites outside of salesforce, but is to be used in salesforce only, for example if you are doing a callout from Apex or browser side javascript back to salesforce. If you want a third party to call into salesforce, do that with an OAuth token which the user can authorize.. Because of these types of abuses, the API session id is no longer exposed in an aura context.

Comment: Hi Robert. As i told you its not an external website its our internal site and we are using it as SSO authenticator for the site that is generated.

Comment: I would like to know if there is a way to use the URL in src attribute in the iframe tag in case if we can. Let us look into the security part with our security team.

Comment: Yes, you can, just pass the url to an aura attribute and set the attribute to the be the src  src="{!v.value}". In this case, please make the attribute private and verify that the value starts with "https:" to prevent XSS

Comment: OK, but if you want to use Salesforce as an Identity Provider, please see the help article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_enable.htm&type=5   Do not pass Salesforce user session data to servers not owned by salesforce, that's not a secure way to do SSO authentication.

Comment: "Yes, you can, just pass the url to an aura attribute and set the attribute to the be the src src="{!v.value}". In this case, please make the attribute private and verify that the value starts with "https:" to prevent XSS –"
this is not going to work.

Anyone who can help here please.